# Convert List of object to String[] with Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

If I have a list of an example class User (shown below), can I create a String array for all the names in the list with one line using lambda?

```
class User{
  String name;
  int id;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.
Given `List<User> users`:

```
String[] names = users.stream().map(user -> user.name).toArray(String[]::new);
```

That is "stream the users, get the name for each one, put them in a new String array."

If your `User` has a `getName()` method, then it would be:

```
String[] names = users.stream().map(User::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
```